# Express route with dynamic params not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```js
router.get('/:id ', (req, res) => {
    res.send(req.params.id);
});
```

When I call this on exmaple "http://localhost/12" I will get an error called "Cannot Get /12"

Any ideas what I am missing out?

Comment: Your variable name is `router`, is this an express router? Where are you mounting it?

Comment: Can you share the complete code ?

Comment: Insufficient information in this question.  We need to be able to follow the routing all the way from the top level.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register your router to main app in your index.js

In your router.js folder

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router()
router.get('/:id ', (req, res) => {
    res.send(req.params.id);
});
```

and in your index.js

```
const express = require('express');
app = express()
app.use(router)
```

Comment: is there a way to add text before it? for example i am getting error when trying to do:

res.send(` the id is ${req.params.id}`) 

i get page 404 result - CANNOT GET/app.js